# How to parse special characters using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, special-characters

I am using Retrofit2 and GET method to fetch content and display it in TextView. in my json content there are some special characters like ñ and when I get response and display it on Textview or in Log it display it like this �.

I tried to add Header with different content types but did not work.

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_LINKS.Base_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

and here is GET method

```
@GET
Call<List<SpeakersData>> GetSpeakers(@Url String url);
```

here is speaker model class.

```
  public class SpeakersData{
  @SerializedName("speaker_title")
  @Expose
  private String speaker_title;
  @SerializedName("speaker_email")
  @Expose
  private String speaker_email;
  @SerializedName("speaker_website")
  @Expose
  private String speaker_website;
```

It's utf-8 or any parsing issue I don't know. I would appreciate if anyone help me out.

Comment: I believe nothing wrong with Retrofit. The problem is when you are trying to show them.

Comment: Can you post your `SpeakersData` model?

Comment: @MohammadZare I updated question with model class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you show them. Since these characters are not in ordinary charset, well, you can show them by the help of `HTML` tags like below:

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));`

let me know the result.

Comment: I tried but it didnot worked. However another thing I noticed when I checked header of api request it's sending me json in text/html instead of application/json